# How to generate random points on a plane that do not overlap?

Tags: distributions, algorithms, random-generation

I want to generate a bunch of random dots on the (x,y) plane, where the coordinates are integers drawn from some distribution F (e.g., the uniform distribution). Each dot is a square of size SxS and I don't want any two dots to overlap on the plane. What is the algorithm I can use to generate that?

Comment: generate points using uniform distribution until you find one that doesn't overlap with existing points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your coordinates $(X,Y)\sim P(x,y)$.

Let $p_i :=(x_i,y_i)$, then $p_1$ will be generated from $P(p_i)$, $p_2$ will be generated from $P(p_2|p_2 \notin \{p_1\})$.

In general,  $p_j \sim P(p_j|p_j \notin \bigcup_{i<j} p_i\})$.

You'll need a way to either draw directly from these conditional distributions or use an acceptance-rejection scheme.